# Customly Spliting months

Tags: date, db2

How do i split month in two? i.e 1-15 and then 15- whatever the remaining days of months for whole year?
it is something like:

```
**Data**                    **Date**
some data                 01-01-2019 to 15-01-2019
some data                 16-01-2019 to 31-01-2019
some data                 01-02-2019 to 15-02-2019
some data                 16-02-2019 to 28-02-2019
```

And so on for whole year or half of year or quarter of year?
Can i do this using DB2?

Comment: What is your input data, what the desired result? What Db2 version / platform? What SQL did you try? Take a look at the Db2 time and date functions

Comment: My desire result is mentioned above and db2 version is 11.1.4.4

Comment: What is your input? A date, a specific month, ...? Please edit your question

Comment: we have data against different dates what i want is it create blocks of dates as i showed above and data lying under that date.

Comment: Like if 3 4 entries fall in between jan1 to jan15 it shows in that block. same with other

Comment: You need the following Db2 functions to construct the corresponding expression in the form of `YYYY-MM-01 to YYYY-MM-15` and `YYYY-MM-16 to YYYY-MM-DD`, where DD is the end date of the corresponding month: `DAYOFMONTH` (to find the end DATE of previous month for given date) and `TO_CHAR` (to format the date representation). Check the following useful link to be familiar with date arithmetic in Db2: [Datetime operations and durations](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023457.html). Try it yourself first and show, what you get.

Comment: And if you are at 11.1 at least, you may use the `FIRST_DAY` / `LAST_DAY` functions as well.

Comment: With this option i will get data or 1 jan to to 15 january but i want the data for whole year do i have to put that much checks or is there any other option

Comment: also it should show that under the window it belongs. i.e in one column it show 2019-01-01 to 2019-01-15 and in other rows it's corresponding data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with base (date_value) as (
 values ('2020-01-01'),('2020-02-05'),('2020-03-10'),('2020-04-15'), 
        ('2020-05-05'),('2020-06-10'),('2020-07-15'),('2020-08-20'), 
        ('2020-09-11'),('2020-10-16'),('2020-11-21'),('2020-12-26') 
) 
select  
  date_value, 
  CASE 
    WHEN (day(date_value) <= 15) 
        THEN CHAR( TO_CHAR(FIRST_DAY(date_value), 'DD-MM-YYYY') || ' to ' || '15-' || LPAD(TO_CHAR(MONTH(date_value)),2, '0') || '-' || TO_CHAR(YEAR(date_value)), 30 )
      ELSE 
        CHAR( '16-' || LPAD(TO_CHAR(MONTH(date_value)),2, '0') || '-' || TO_CHAR(YEAR(date_value)) || ' to ' || TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(date_value), 'DD-MM-YYYY') , 30) 
  END  BUCKET   
from base
```

The initial part is just to produce some sample dates.

this will produce the following result:

```
DATE_VALUE BUCKET
---------- ------------------------------
2020-01-01 01-01-2020 to 15-01-2020
2020-02-05 01-02-2020 to 15-02-2020
2020-03-10 01-03-2020 to 15-03-2020
2020-04-15 01-04-2020 to 15-04-2020
2020-05-05 01-05-2020 to 15-05-2020
2020-06-10 01-06-2020 to 15-06-2020
2020-07-15 01-07-2020 to 15-07-2020
2020-08-20 16-08-2020 to 31-08-2020
2020-09-11 01-09-2020 to 15-09-2020
2020-10-16 16-10-2020 to 31-10-2020
2020-11-21 16-11-2020 to 30-11-2020
2020-12-26 16-12-2020 to 31-12-2020

  12 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Highly Appreciated! Thank you